# How to use mage/validation on password input

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.4

hello I have this field in checkout, I would like use 'mage/validation' to verify if the is true or not.

I tried, but it doesn't work, maybe I didn't understand how it works :

```
let password = $('[for="customer-password"]').next().find('.input-text').validation('isValid')
console.log(password)
```

**MY HTML**

```
<div class="field amcheckout-password required" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible, css: {required: isPassword}"
    style="display: block;"> <label class="label" for="customer-password" style="top: 16px; font-size: 16px;"> <span
            data-bind="i18n: 'Password'">Mot de passe</span></label>

    <input class="input-text mage-error" type="password" name="password" id="customer-password">

</div>
```

Also I added a button

```
<div class="buttonContinue buttonContinueStepOne"> Continuer</div>
```

With his js

```
$('.buttonContinueStepOne').click(function(){
    console.log('nextstep')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add data-validation to the password input field

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'isValid':true}
```

So when based on **isValid** function it will validate the password

**Try this**

```
<input class="input-text mage-error" type="password" name="password" data-validate="{required:true, 'isValid':true}" id="customer-password">
```

**UPDATE:**

Make this disabled by default:

```
<div class="buttonContinue buttonContinueStepOne" disabled>Continuer</div>
```

Then add the below code, where condition is **if your validation return true**

```
let password = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonContinue');
password.disabled = false;
```

Comment: I appended a button with jquery, is it possible to disable this button if form is not valid ?

Comment: Can you please share the code

Comment: I added in the main post

Comment: @Kevinami Updated the answer

Comment: ok, but How do you verify if it's true or not , just using this ? $('.myformclass').validation('isValid')

Comment: What you are getting by console: $('.myformclass').validation('isValid'). If true or false then add if condition in query